# Solve the system of linear equations by Gaussian elimination and back-substitution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: **Question 1**:Form the adjunct matrix and reduce it to echelon form.] **Question 1**:Form the adjunct matrix and reduce it to echelon form. I dont know how to write matrices here, so i snap a picture of my operation. Did I do it right?

**Question 2**: Use back-substitution to solve for x, y and z

For this question, i got z = $ {11\over 3} $ , y = $ {28\over 3} $ and x = $ {-26\over 3} $

**Question 3:** Geometrically, what does the solution represent?

I'm a bit confuse about this question. Did the solution represent a rectangle? Can someone care to explain it to me?

Comment: $ax+by+cz=d$ represents a plane in 3D. The unique solution of your system represents the point where these planes intersect.

Comment: Matrices: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in the first row reduction. If you do the operation $R_2+R_1\rightarrow R_2$, your row $R_2$ should be $0,3,5$ not $0,-1,5$

Comment: Thanks! So y = (28/9) and x = (-22/9)?

Answer (score 0):

Q1,2)I don't understand what you do by the way you explain it over the $\to$ so I'll just go ahead and tell you an easier way on how to do it.

1)Swap row 1 with row 3

2)Add (row1)/3 to row 2

3)Multiply row 2 by 3

4)Substract (row1)/3 from row 3

5)Multiply row3 by 3/2

6)Swap row 2 with row 3

7)Add (row2)/5 to row 3

8)Multiply row3 by 5/6

9)Divide row3 by 11

10)Substract row3 from row 2

11)Divide row2 by 5

12)Add 7(row2) to row 1

13)Substract 4(row3) from row 1

14)Divide row1 by 3

You now have a 3x3 identity matrix augmented with your solutions. No back-substitution needed(well, theoritically it's the same thing). They're different from your answer. They are; $$x=\frac{51}{11}, y=\frac{13}{11}, z=\frac{12}{11}$$

Q3)The solution represents the point in 3D space where your 3 planes intersect.

Comment: But it stated in the question that I have to use back to back substitution. However, will try on operation later. Btw, the arrow means write in back to Row